# Can't use CUPS' Authentication on Windows 10 Laptop

Tags: printing, samba, raspberry-pi, authentication, cups

My question is practically identical to the one found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1170767/how-can-i-use-cups-basic-authentication-from-a-windows-client).  In short, I have a samba printing server with CUPS as the backend support on a raspberry pi.  I have configured CUPS to require basic authentication from a valid-user.  I can access my printing server from a Linux computer and authenticate with no issues, but my windows 10 computer doesn't prompt any authentication when I add the printer, regardless of how I try to add it.  Instead, I get a "windows couldn't connect to the printer" error message.  I've tried doing all of these ways but nothing works:

- http://username:password@server:631/printers/MyPrinter
- http://username@server:631/printers/MyPrinter
- http://server:631/printers/MyPrinter

The windows computer can print fine when authentication isn't required, so the connection between the computer and the printer doesn't seem to be the issue.  Has anyone experienced anything like this, or have any suggestions as to how I can authenticate?  Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: Does active directory play any role in the configuration you describe?

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm not familiar with active directory, but I'm reading through my samba config file and it says that the server role is set as a standalone server and not an active directory domain controller.  I apologize if this is irrelevant information or not what you were asking - I'm a bit out of my element with this.